# Jquery Script Tag in Header

Tags: wordpress, tags, jquery

I know this is a really basic question, so forgive me. I have a script that works in a jfiddle, but I want to put it in my header and I can't figure out how to call it with a script tag and event handler(?).

Here's the script:

```
var retrieveValue = function(ev){
        var $this = $(this),
            val = $this.data('value');

        if (val) {
            $this.val(val);
        }
    },
    hideValue = function(ev){
        var $this = $(this);

        $this.data('value', $this.val());
        $this.val($this.val().replace(/^\d{5}/, '*****'));
    };

$('#field_a7afui').focus(retrieveValue);

$('#field_a7afui').blur(hideValue);

$('#form_hv3hcs').submit(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    retrieveValue.call($('#field_a7afui')[0], ev);
    alert($('#field_a7afui').val());
    hideValue.call($('#field_a7afui')[0], ev);
});
```

Can someone please tell me what I need to put at the beginning and end of this just to throw it in my Wordpress header and call it a day?

Here's my jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d5KaJ/40/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's what you were asking for...
into a `script` tag like:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

jQuery(function( $ ) {   

        // CODE HERE

} )();

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I get a parse error on the last line with }); I think because adding jQuery(function( $ ){  opens up another bracket, but adding a second closing bracket at the end doesn't fix the error.

Comment: Yes! I see you updated it. There's just one thing I had to fix (you have an opening parenthetical in front of jquery(function. I removed that, and it works like a charm. Thanks!